# How to get operating system with autoconf?

Tags: operating-system, autotools, autoconf

I'm trying to figure out how to use autoconf to get the operating system, but whenever I try to use `AC_CANONICAL_HOST`, it just gives me this error: `configure: error: cannot find install-sh, install.sh, or shtool in "." "./.." "./../.."`

Answer (score 1):

`autoreconf -fvi` will get `automake` to write `install-sh`.